# Tweepy list_members python

Tags: tweepy

I created a list on twitter and added a user to it. Then I finally figured out how to write the code without an error. I am a newbie. Then Lo and behold when i get data it is whacked out. I have no idea what to do with it.

All I want is to get the usernames of everyone in the the list.

Here is the code:

```
the_list = api.list_members('username', 'listname')
for user in the_list:
    print user
```

Here is what I get:

tweepy.models.User object at 0x90b78ec
(0, 0)

That doesn't look like list_members to me. 
I want to create a normal python list of just the usernames.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element of the list is a `User` object, which holds more information about the user than just their name. If you want just the names, do

```
the_list = [u.screen_name for u in the_list]
```

after calling `api.list_members`. Or you can combine the two:

```
the_list = [u.screen_name for u in api_list_members('username','listname')
```

or you can extract the names only when you're displaying them:

```
the_list = api.list_members('username','listname')
for user in the_list:
    print user.screen_name
```

Incidentally, you should choose a more informative name than `the_list`. Perhaps `user_names` or `list_members` or something.

Comment: I tried the bottom before I wrote the post. Every time I try .screen_name, unless its with something like get_user, I get this:

Comment: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'screen_name'

Comment: all the methods listed are sort append count index etc

Comment: Aha. `api.list_members` actually returns not just the list but a tuple. Its first element is the list you want. So: `api.list_members('username','listname')[0]` is the list and you can do all the above things to it. (I'm not too impressed with the Tweepy documentation, I have to say...)

Comment: Ahaa! Thanks. I was doing for user[0] in the_list

Comment: I thought I would be on that forever. LOL Thanks alot. I agree on docs.

Comment: @gareth-mccaughan, Twitter paginates results, so `api.list_members('username','listname')[0]` is only the first 20 or so members of the list. If you want to access all list members, you can use `tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, 'username', 'listname').items()`