# Get the members from a Twitter list with python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to create a Data frame with some data from the European Parliament members. However I am struggling with the data received when using the tweepy package.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Iterate through all members of the owner's list
member in tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, 'Europarl_EN', 'all-meps-on-twitter').items():
   m = member
   print(member)
```

The problem is I do not how to get a readable table after this. Also I tried this just in order to get the names:

```
lel = api.list_members('Europarl_EN', 'all-meps-on-twitter', -10)
for i in lel: 
   print(i.name)
```

And the output is:

Jaromír Kohlíček
István Ujhelyi
Deli Andor
Maria Grapini
Winkler Gyula
LefterisChristoforou
Mircea Diaconu
Maria Heubuch
Daniel Buda
Marijana Petir
Maite Pagazaurtundúa
Janice Atkinson
Andrew Lewer
Martina Michels
Joachim Starbatty
Peter Jahr
Emil Radev
József Nagy
Quisthoudt-Rowohl
Dominique Bilde

All in, my intention is to transform lel into a dataframe or in the worst scenario to get the usernames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tweepy list\_members python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469768/tweepy-list-members-python)

Comment: Well my problem is that I want more than the names, I basically want to structure the list that I receive to a Dataframe

Comment: Flag retracted, I'll keep the link there just in case it helps others though